# Loop for multiple models

Tags: r, loops

I have a model like this one (see below) and I need to run it for each row of data. In the example for 9 observations. I am trying to create a loop to run the model as many times as observations but I also need to put each value in a data.frame. Could it be possible to obtain a data.frame with each value for the different models? Something like:

Results <- as.data.frame(c(0.29,0.30,0.27,0.25,0.31,0.30,0.32,0.33,0.29))

```
####Model####
#Model from Estabroke and Neale 2013
require(OpenMx)

V1 <- c(1,2.4,6,8,9,5,6,7,8)
V2 <- c(1,3,6,8.6,9,6,6,7,8)
V3 <- c(1,3,6,5,9.2,5,6,7,8)
V4 <- c(1,7,6,9,9,5.5,6,6,8)
V5 <- c(1,2,2,8,5.4,5,6,5,8)

exampleData <-as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5))

factorModel <- mxModel("Initial Model",
                       mxData(exampleData, "raw"),
                       mxMatrix(type="Full", nrow=1, ncol=5,
                                free=TRUE, values=0, name="alpha"),
                       mxMatrix("Full", 1, 1, FALSE, 0, name="mu"),
                       mxMatrix("Full", 1, 5, TRUE, 0.8, name="lambda"),
                       mxMatrix("Symm", 1, 1, FALSE, 1, name="phi"),mxMatrix("Diag", 5, 5, TRUE, 0.6, name="theta"),
                       mxAlgebra(t(lambda) %*% phi %*% lambda + theta, name="cov"),
                       mxAlgebra(alpha + mu %*% lambda, name="mean"),
                       
                       mxExpectationNormal(covariance = "cov", means = "mean", dimnames=names(exampleData)),
                       mxFitFunctionML())

factorResults <- mxRun(factorModel)
fsModel <- mxModel(factorResults, name="FactorScore")

fsModel$alpha@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$lambda@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$theta@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$mu@free[,] <- TRUE

fsModel@expectation  <- mxExpectationNormal("theta", "mean",names(exampleData))

fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[1,], "raw")

fullModel <- mxModel("Weighted Factor Score Model",
                     fsModel,
                     mxAlgebra(1 / ((2*pi)^(1/2) * sqrt(det(FactorScore.phi))) *
                                 exp(-.5*(FactorScore.mu %&% solve(FactorScore.phi))),
                               name="weight"),
                     mxAlgebra(-2*log(weight %x% FactorScore.objective),
                               name="alg"),
                     mxAlgebraObjective("alg"))

fsResults <- mxRun(fullModel)

fsResults$weight$result[1,1]
```

I need to run it changing this line (so in this example 9 times)

```
fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[1,], "raw")
fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[2,], "raw")
fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[3,], "raw")
```

...

```
fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[9,], "raw")
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```r
require(OpenMx)
library(purrr)  # line added
library(tibble)  # line added

V1 <- c(1,2.4,6,8,9,5,6,7,8)
V2 <- c(1,3,6,8.6,9,6,6,7,8)
V3 <- c(1,3,6,5,9.2,5,6,7,8)
V4 <- c(1,7,6,9,9,5.5,6,6,8)
V5 <- c(1,2,2,8,5.4,5,6,5,8)

exampleData <-as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5))

factorModel <- mxModel("Initial Model",
                       mxData(exampleData, "raw"),
                       mxMatrix(type="Full", nrow=1, ncol=5,
                                free=TRUE, values=0, name="alpha"),
                       mxMatrix("Full", 1, 1, FALSE, 0, name="mu"),
                       mxMatrix("Full", 1, 5, TRUE, 0.8, name="lambda"),
                       mxMatrix("Symm", 1, 1, FALSE, 1, name="phi"),mxMatrix("Diag", 5, 5, TRUE, 0.6, name="theta"),
                       mxAlgebra(t(lambda) %*% phi %*% lambda + theta, name="cov"),
                       mxAlgebra(alpha + mu %*% lambda, name="mean"),
                       
                       mxExpectationNormal(covariance = "cov", means = "mean", dimnames=names(exampleData)),
                       mxFitFunctionML())

factorResults <- mxRun(factorModel)
#> Running Initial Model with 15 parameters
fsModel <- mxModel(factorResults, name="FactorScore")

fsModel$alpha@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$lambda@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$theta@free[,] <- FALSE
fsModel$mu@free[,] <- TRUE

fsModel@expectation  <- mxExpectationNormal("theta", "mean",names(exampleData))

results_df <- map(1:9, \(x){ # line added
  fsModel@data <- mxData(exampleData[x,], "raw") # line changed
  
  fullModel <- mxModel("Weighted Factor Score Model",
                       fsModel,
                       mxAlgebra(1 / ((2*pi)^(1/2) * sqrt(det(FactorScore.phi))) *
                                   exp(-.5*(FactorScore.mu %&% solve(FactorScore.phi))),
                                 name="weight"),
                       mxAlgebra(-2*log(weight %x% FactorScore.objective),
                                 name="alg"),
                       mxAlgebraObjective("alg"))
  
  fsResults <- mxRun(fullModel)
  
  tibble(x = x, result = fsResults$weight$result[1,1])  # line changed
}) |>  # line added
  list_rbind()   # line added

results_df

#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>       x result
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.305
#> 2     2  0.267
#> 3     3  0.148
#> 4     4  0.238
#> 5     5  0.262
#> 6     6  0.172
#> 7     7  0.145
#> 8     8  0.193
#> 9     9  0.231
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That works. I am now going to adapt it to my dataset and full script :) PS: I have changed this line list_rbind()  to  dplyr::bind_rows()   # line added since the required package was not available for my R version. Thank you so much again!